# gradle-play-publisher: Task 'bootstrap' or 'publishApk' not working

Tags: android, gradle, publishing, gradle-play-publisher

I am trying to integrate the gradle plugin https://github.com/Triple-T/gradle-play-publisher in version *2.0.0-beta1* to automatically upload a new version of an APK to the PlayStore.

I followed the instructions and created a service account and linked it to my PlayStore account.
Then I added my key document (JSON) in the app/build.gradle.

If I call `./gradlew tasks` in my Android project, I now also see the task 'bootstrap', `publishApk`,... but when I call e.g. `bootstrap` or `publishApk`  nothing happens.
No Taks does anythink right now :(
When I call `./gradlew -i bootstrap` it says:

> Task :app:bootstrap UP-TO-DATE Skipping task ':app:bootstrap' as it
>   has no actions.

Does anyone have any idea where my mistake is?

***FYI***:
I'm trying to do this in Android Studio 3.2.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Oh damn....

after reading the bug https://github.com/Triple-T/gradle-play-publisher/issues/81 and the corresponding answers until the end i noticed that my release-build has set the property `debuggable true` at the moment (due to tests). After removing this the plugin works as expected.

Sorry for the confusion ;)

Comment: You saved me. Again!